# Multi-language integration on Slack with API.AI

Tags: multilingual, slack, slack-api, dialogflow-es

I have made a bot with [API.AI](https://api.ai) and I am using it with [Slack](http://slack.com). I'm trying to integrate a [multi-language agent](https://api.ai/docs/multi-language) to it, however I don't know how to set the lang tag of the messages coming from Slack.

My bot supports English and French and even if the user have Slack set in french, the lang tag remains "EN" (English).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check out this post from Slack: [Detecting the locale of users, channels, and other conversations](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-locale-locale-locale)?